# Ubuntu wont start up after uninstalling packages with synaptic

Tags: server, startup, uninstall, synaptic

I have had Ubuntu for a while and I uninstalled a few packages with synaptic. I then restarted the computer and it turns on the screen for a second, then the screen says "no signal imput" and turns off, but the computer is still on.
The packages were for mysql, php5, and xserver. I have no idea what is going on and I REALLY need to use it. PLEASE HELP :(!

FYI I didn't know at first how to uninstall the packages using synaptic so I saved it as a text file on accident. I opened it and one of the packages was along the lines of ubuntu-desktop. Is this the problem? If so, how do I re install it. I cant afford a clean install, because I have many files and programs that are irreplaceable.

Comment: I just restarted and it got to the bootloader and I chose ubuntugeneric... and it just turned off the screen again

Comment: "*The packages were for mysql, php5, and **xserver**.*" I don't think I know enough to help you, but I think that's your problem. Why were you uninstalling the X server?

Comment: i thought it was some program this mysql server installed to my system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xserver package and ubuntu-desktop is metapackages and you can install theme again by giving :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop xserver
```

To do the above your computer should be connected on a internet network (LAN).
But even if you can not fix your problem your files are OK. You can have access to them by using a live CD/USB of Ubuntu and copying them to an externel disk. Then you can make a clean install safely.